# Why and when to use claims-based authentication?

Tags: 2010, claims-based-auth, classic-mode-auth

I understand MS recommends claims-based authentication for new installations of SP 2010. This authentication model is based on WIF. It is a new authentication model available in SP 2010.

But, I would like to know:

- Why it is recommended to use claims-based authentication in new installations?
- When should I pick claims-based authentication over classic authentication? and visa verse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSDN: [Why Use Claims-Based Identity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee535229)